# Need VM solution for studio environement

Tags: mac-osx, virtual-machines

Newbie question here. 
I'm trying to figure out a solution for my studio. We have around 50 artists that are working on iMacs but due to security risks we are going to be disconnecting them from the internet and we want to instead give them access to a VM to do their web surfing.

So I'm trying to figure out how I can give them access to a VM that would be connected to the internet but not their iMacs.

Comment: This is a really weird way to solve this problem. Give the users non-admin accounts, have good backups in place, and be prepared to image machines that do get compromised.

Comment: We do shows for for broadcast and we're wanting to reduce the risk for ransomware or any other type of file access from the outside world. We know there is always a risk when delivering but we want to show the networks that we are being very cautious.

Comment: Why not just setup a few wifi points and some $200 Android tablets for browsing, then?

Comment: Thought about doing this as well as using thin clients but a lot of our artists use images from the web for reference so I'm thinking if I can get them to launch a VM from their computer remotely then they could use the production computer's screen grab function to at least get that image to use in their software.

Comment: I think you should find other ways to show the networks that you are being very cautious.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas come to mind. Setup the VMs with a default gateway and DNS for Internet access while not giving the MACs such information. Another option would be to setup a proxy server and have the VMs connect to that for Internet access.

Comment: I like this idea. I'll explore it and see if this will meet the goals.